# Но до тех пор(,) пока огонь горит, каждый его по-своему хранит

Tags: запятые

Нужна запятая?

> Но до тех пор(,) пока огонь горит, каждый его по-своему хранит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно:

*Но до тех пор / пока **огОнь горит**, // каждый его **по-свОему** **хранит**.*

Придаточное времени **в препозиции**, расчленение союза **нежелательно** (оно должно быть обоснованным).

Но грамматике и по смыслу СПП делится **на две (не на три)** части, которые противопоставлены **друг другу**.

**В каждой части** (фонетической фразе) делается **одно** логическое (фразовое) ударение.

Comment: Как говорится, нежелательно, но разрешено. :)

Comment: Выбирайте, Максим,  Решение задачи – это выбор)  СЕМАНТИЕСКИЙ принцип мне представляется основным: грамматика, структура  и интонация ему соответствуют.

Answer (score 1):

Четыре варианта:

***Но, до тех, пор пока** огонь горит, каждый его по-своему хранит* — ставится пауза прсле союза НО и стоит логическое ударение на первую часть союза ДО ТЕХ ПОР ПОКА;

***Но, до тех пор пока** огонь горит, каждый его по-своему хранит* — логическое ударение на первую часть союза не падает; стоит пауза после НО;

***Но до тех пор, пока** огонь горит, каждый его по-своему хранит* — ставится логическое ударение на первую часть союза;

***Но до тех пор пока** огонь горит, каждый его по-своему хранит* — ни логических ударений, ни пауз нет.

---

Вывод: зависит от того, ставил автор логические ударения и паузы, — автор решает насчет запятых.